# Issue with getimagesize() warning, when a large file is uploaded

Tags: php

I have a wee problem here. This is part of a string of code that validates an image file before it's uploaded.

```
//Check if the image is real or fake (fyi 1 is good 0 is not good)
if($uploadOK){
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["banner_708"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false || !empty($check)) {
        $uploadOK = 1;
    } 
    else {
        $uploadOK = 0;
        array_push($banner_msg_array, "This is not a valid image.");
    }
}
```

The problem is when a file is too large.  What ends up happening in the above code is `getimagesize()` evaluates to empty. Then I get my own array_push message in the `else` statement, but also a system error:

> Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in

I thought that the above logic `if($check !== false || !empty($check))` would eliminate this error; if it's false or empty, then go to `else` and push the array. It sort of does, but why the system error? How can I get rid of this?

I do have the overall code checking for file size, but it doesn't matter in what order I place it, before or after the above code, I still get this system warning when a file is too large, and I think it's because `getimagesize()` has nothing to evaluate. The problem is what can be changed to eliminate this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you never check if the image actually got uploaded. There might be a size limit configured either on the client or on the server side.

Comment: I think it returns array, maybe you can check for length

Comment: How can the `if` eliminate the error? The error happens on the line before it.

Comment: You should check `$_FILES["banner_708"]["error"]` to see if it uploaded successfully.

Comment: You also have `if($uploadOK)` before you set that variable in the `if/else` statements. And you should use `true/false` rather than `1/0`.

Comment: Thanks Barmar.  I know it does!  lol.  the problem is not knowing wth to do abt it :)  I mess with code for hours before coming on here, so I need leads or answers :) ...update.  just seen your suggestions.  OK so I'll do `if($check = $_FILES["banner_708"]["error"]){...` before this statement.  or something to that effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether the file was received correctly.

```
if ($_FILES["banner_708"]["error"]){
    $uploadOK = 0;
    $banner_msg_array[] = "Image could not be uploaded";
} else {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["banner_708"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false || !empty($check)) {
        $uploadOK = 1;
    } 
    else {
        $uploadOK = 0;
        array_push($banner_msg_array, "This is not a valid image.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I made a comment & refreshed and this was here :)  Works.  ugh.  Is it just me or is 3/4 of coding checks and security.